# How do i add to the List<string> also the files directory and then getting to a single string var only the file name and dir from the List?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public static string filetoupload;
        int count = 0;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> files = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\")
            .GetFiles("*.avi")
            .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f.Name) + " " + FileSizeDisplay(f,70))
            .ToList();

            for (int i = files.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (!files[i].EndsWith("MB") || files[i].EndsWith("0 MB"))
                {
                    files.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }

            filetoupload = files[count];
            count += 1;
        }
```

And the method FileSizeDisplay:

```
static string FileSizeDisplay(FileInfo f, int filterfilesize)
        {
            string fn = "";
            double maximumfilessize = filterfilesize;
            const int MB = 1024 * 1024;
            if (f.Length <= maximumfilessize * MB)
            {
                fn = Math.Round(((double)f.Length / MB), 1).ToString() + " MB";
            }
            return fn;
        }
```

What i'm getting now in the List files is:

test.avi 2MB
test1.avi 30MB
test2.avi 15MB
test3.avi 0.1MB

But now i need to change the List to be:

d:\test.avi 2MB
d:\test1.avi 30MB
c:\test2.avi 15MB
e:\test\test\test3.avi 0.1MB

I need to add to the List also the directory of each file.

Then i need later to get each file only the directo and file name:
So the string var filetoupload will contain for example:

d:\test.avi

And next click

d:\test1.avi

Next click

c:\test2.avi

I tried to change in this place to FullName:

```
Path.GetFileName(f.Name)
```

I did f.FullName but it didn't change much.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `FullName` property of `FileInfo` instead of the `Name` property and get rid of `Path.GetFileName` which strips off the directory part of a path.

```
...
.Select(f => f.FullName + " " + FileSizeDisplay(f, 70))
...
```